# How can i save the href value after a link has been clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

More specifically a client has asked that when their link on another site has been clicked, and the user is brought back to the clients site. Can the href value of the users clicked link be saved and used again in another function.

For ex. I clicked the clients logo on another site and it brought to the clients site. Now the content on the clients site is filtered based on where i came from.

I found the following which saves the href of a clicked link on current site.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href')) someFunction.href = $(this).attr('href');
  });
});

function someFunction(a) {
  window.setTimeout("console.log(someFunction.href);",200);
```

But im not sure how to store that data and use it again.

Comment: Do you have access to the "other" site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the "other" site, I'd recommend just attaching a query parameter to the link, such as: `<a href="www.targetsite.com/?referrer=parentsite.com">Client site</a>`. That's a very easy and dependable way to go at it.

Another way would be server-side, using [`$_SERVER\['HTTP_REFERER'\]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

If you want to access it client-side, you can use [`document.referrer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer).

Note that the last two (especially the client-side) are not as dependable, though you should generally be fine. Also note that `document.referrer` **will be empty** if the parent site is HTTPS and the target site is HTTP.

### Example

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  if(document.referrer === 'http://www.affiliatesite.com/product/myproduct')
      filterMyContent('affiliate')
});
```

Comment: Great! This is exactly what i was looking for. Since the other sites will be affiliate sites, i will instruct the client in the future to use the query selector on any links given.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is query string parameters. For example, if the link to your clients site that was clicked from elsewhere were `myclientsite.com?from=google.com`, you could parse that value (from=google.com) and use it to change content on your clients page. See https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript for details on parsing these values with javascript. This only works with the caveat that you can control the url of the link on the external site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to set the link on the other site you could add a query string to the URL e.g. `clientsite.com?referrer=othersite.com`. Then change the site based on the referrer.

If you can't change the link on the other site you could try see where the user has come from using the referrer (although this isn't always very reliable)

```
//Javascript
var referrer = document.referrer;

//PHP
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```